# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 vscode on mac

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

I don't know why but I have this simple code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
 std::cout << "hello world"" << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

when I try to compile in the terminal whit:

```
gcc -o main main.cpp
```

appears undefined symbols for architecture x86_64.

Comment: `g++` is the C++ compiler driver, not `gcc`

Comment: `gcc` is the driver program to build C programs. `g++` is the driver program for C++.

Comment: ok now it works. Doing this command from terminal is the same as doing the command in the extension "code runner"? sorry but I'am new in vscode.